# Variable is undefined out of ajax scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, scope

how to make visible this var (rec_count) out of ajax scope? I can't understand this about ajax scope. thanks!

```
function showImage(str){        
    $.ajax({                                 
        url:            'getimg.php',
        type:       "GET",
        data:           "q="+str,
        dataType:   'json',
        success:    function(data){
            rec_count = data.count;
            console.log('inside: ' + rec_count)
        }
    });
}

$( document ).ready(function(){
    $('body').click(function(){
        showImage(4);
        console.log('outside: ' + rec_count)
    });
});
```

Comment: AJAX is async by default...

Comment: We need to turn this into a drinking game.

Comment: `rec_count` is a global. Your problems have nothing to do with scope.

Comment: @squint — You mean you haven't already?

Comment: @Quentin: No, and it's probably for the best. Most days I'd be plastered before noon.

Comment: Addtl info that deals specifically with the illusion of it being a scope issue: [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Comment: thanks, i read that.